# Stack of the Fragment's

Tags: android, kotlin, backstack

Имеется некий вопрос. Я некое время изучаю android. Мне понадобилось реализовать ТРИ фрагмента в одной activity (между собой show/hide). Переход между фрагментами: делаю через интерфейс (определяю interface во фрагменте, activity наследует этот interface и переопределяет, и вызывается общий метод, который добавляет новый фрагмент, скрывает текущий или показывает, соответственно создается stack фрагментов.) Когда я дохожу до последнего фрагмента и нажимаю на кнопку back, то происходит переход на предыдущий фрагмент, НО отображаются все скрытые ранее фрагменты (первый и второй фрагмент), но в stack они ещё хранятся, ну и при повторном нажатие на кнопку back, скрывается второй фрагмент. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
private fun pushFragments(tag: String, fragment: Fragment) {
    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    val ft = manager.beginTransaction()

    if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
    }

    val fragmentFirst = manager.findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_ENTRANCE)
    val fragmentSecond = manager.findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_SIGN_IN)
    val fragmentThird = manager.findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_PERSONAL_DATA)

        if (fragmentFirst != null) {
            ft.hide(fragmentFirst)
        }
    if (fragmentSecond != null)  {
        ft.hide(fragmentSecond)
    }
    if (fragmentThird != null) {
        ft.hide(fragmentThird)
    }

    if (tag === Const.TAG_ENTRANCE) {
        if (fragmentFirst != null) {
            ft.show(fragmentFirst)
        }
    }
    if (tag === Const.TAG_SIGN_IN) {
        if (fragmentSecond != null) {
            ft.show(fragmentSecond)
        }
    }
    if (tag === Const.TAG_PERSONAL_DATA) {
        if (fragmentThird != null) {
            ft.show(fragmentThird)
        }
    }

    ft.addToBackStack(null).commit()

    Log.d(TAG, "Количество в стеке:" + supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount)
}
```

Comment: Представляется очевидным, что вы устанавливаете оба фрагмента в состояние "видимый". Что-то ещё сложно сказать, не видя кода.

Comment: мне кажется проблема в фоне. Попробуйте на всех 3-ех фрагментах установить в main layout какой-нибудь фон.

Comment: @Tony, спасибо, так и есть, я бы и не догадался до этого, если бы не вы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в фоне. Установите на всех 3-ех фрагментах в main layout какой-нибудь background.

Comment: проблема осталась, на данный момент я  не вижу оба фрагмента сразу, НО, эти фрагменты находятся друг под другом, т.е., если нажать в определенную область, сработает кнопка первого фрагмента, хотя так не должно быть(

Comment: @izlom а можете код как вы фрагменты добавляете показать

Comment: вот код:
private fun pushFragments(tag: String, fragment: Fragment) {
      val manager = supportFragmentManager
      val ft = manager.beginTransaction()

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
             ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
         }

        val fragmentFirst = manager.findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_ENTRANCE)
        val fragmentSecond = manager.findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_SIGN_IN)
        val fragmentThird = manager.findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_PERSONAL_DATA)

Comment: @izlom тут мало информации. Должны быть такие моменты как .commit

Comment: Я не знаю, как правильно код вставлять здесь, чтобы не было превышения по символам(
if (fragmentFirst != null) {
            ft.hide(fragmentFirst)
        }

if (tag === Const.TAG_ENTRANCE) {
            if (fragmentFirst != null) {
                ft.show(fragmentFirst)
            }
        }
//Эти методы между собой повторяются, для каждого фрагмента
ft.addToBackStack(null).commit()

Comment: я вставил код в вопрос

Comment: @izlom у них походу не вызывается метод hide. Мне так кажется. Проверьте.